# How do I find out how many records of 1 model have associated objects of an association?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, active-record-query

I have two models - `Property` & `Photos`.

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
end
```

All I want to do is create a scope that returns only the Properties that actually have photos (i.e. `photos.count > 0`).

I have tried a million iterations of queries, and they don't work for one reason or another.

See some examples of what I have tried and the results:

```
[32] pry(main)> Property.includes(:photos).where('photos.count > 0').count
   (4.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "properties"."id") FROM "properties" LEFT OUTER JOIN "photos" ON "photos"."property_id" = "properties"."id" WHERE (photos.count > 0)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 1: ..."photos"."property_id" = "properties"."id" WHERE (photos.cou...
                                                             ^
[33] pry(main)> Property.joins(:photos).where('photos.count > 0').count
   (11.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "properties" INNER JOIN "photos" ON "photos"."property_id" = "properties"."id" WHERE (photos.count > 0)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 1: ..."photos"."property_id" = "properties"."id" WHERE (photos.cou...
                                                             ^

[38] pry(main)> Property.joins(:photos).count("properties.id").count
   (158.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(properties.id) FROM "properties" INNER JOIN "photos" ON "photos"."property_id" = "properties"."id"
NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for 72604:Fixnum
from (pry):38:in `__pry__'

[39] pry(main)> Property.joins(:photos).count("properties.id")
   (50.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(properties.id) FROM "properties" INNER JOIN "photos" ON "photos"."property_id" = "properties"."id"
=> 72604

[40] pry(main)> Photo.joins(:properties).count("photos.id")
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'properties' was not found on Photo; perhaps you misspelled it?
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.5/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:112:in `build'

[41] pry(main)> Photo.joins(:property).count("photos.id")
   (65.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(photos.id) FROM "photos" INNER JOIN "properties" ON "properties"."id" = "photos"."property_id"
=> 72604

[42] pry(main)> Photo.joins(:property).count("photos.id")
   (60.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(photos.id) FROM "photos" INNER JOIN "properties" ON "properties"."id" = "photos"."property_id"
=> 72604

[43] pry(main)> Property.joins(:photos).count("properties.id").distinct
   (46.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(properties.id) FROM "properties" INNER JOIN "photos" ON "photos"."property_id" = "properties"."id"
NoMethodError: undefined method `distinct' for 72604:Fixnum
from (pry):43:in `__pry__'

[44] pry(main)> Property.joins(:photos).distinct.count("properties.id")
=> 0
```

This should be simple, but for some reason it's much more difficult than I expected.

Thoughts?

Comment: Check I have posted answer for rails-3, Please test it.

Comment: `Property.joins(:photos)` _should_ give you access to properties that have photos. But you could also try `Property.joins(:photos).having('COUNT(photos) > 0').group('properties.id')`

Answer (score 1):

In order to get only the `Properties` that actually have `photos` (i.e. `photos.count > 0`), you need to perform `inner join` of two tables.

In rails 5, you can do it by below command

```
Property.joins(:photos)
```

This will be transformed to SQL as

```
SELECT  "properties".* FROM "properties" INNER JOIN "photos" ON "photos"."property_id" = "properties"."id"
```

If you want to add more conditions on your queries, you can add `Where` clause

```
Property.joins(:photos).where(properties: {id: [1, 2]})
```

Comment: Where condition just:
`Property.joins(:photos).where(id: [1, 2])`
is enought

Comment: correct. However, I prefer writing joins with object to avoid misunderstanding when looking at it

Answer (score 0):

In **Rails-5**, you can use *left_outer_joins*,

```
Property.left_outer_joins(:photos).where(photos: {id: nil})
```

SQL generated will be,

```
SELECT properties.*
FROM properties 
LEFT OUTER JOIN photos 
ON photos.property_id = property.id
WHERE photos.id IS NULL
```

In **Rails-3**, You can try following

```
Property.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON properties.id = photos.property_id").where(photos: {id: nil})
```

Comment: Interesting, so I guess you did the opposite, where this query finds those properties with no photos......that's a clever approach. That's what you expect the result to be, right?

Comment: Is there a Rails-3 version of doing `.not.where.(photos: {id: nil})`?

Comment: @marcamillion yes, great that you get it. I worked once on rails-3 and I used to do it like `where("photos.id IS NOT NULL")`

Comment: Wouldn't left joins return properties without photos? I thought they wanted only properties *with* photos

Comment: @MikeHeft I focused on _returns only the Properties that actually have photos_ sentence

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm saying. Left outer joins will return properties with and without photos, whereas regular joins will will only return properties _that actually have photos_. I think their issue was trying to put an aggregate function in the where query. I commented on the question where they could try using `having` with group. But they really shouldn't need all that as `Property.joins(:photos)` will return Properties _that actually have photos_

Comment: @MikeHeft hehe, I think you missed something here, see if property with id 2 have 4 photos then your query will produce 4 rows properties with id = 2 for 4 photos. So here we do not need repetition I guess. check with that.

Comment: Actually it won't. Property.joins(:photos) will return Properties that have photos associated with it. Propery.joins('left outer join ....') will return properties with and without photos. hehe. check with that. While you're checking where photos.id is null, you're using the left out join wrong. plain join or inner join will do that for you. hehe, check with that

Comment: I'll admit I didn't see the `.where(photos: {id: nil})` but even still, you're using left outer join wrong.  regular joins(:photos) will return the desired records. you should only use left join when you want all the properties that bot have and do not have photos

Comment: @MikeHeft I will check that. Can you post answer and evaluate with test in your local  if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Using `Property.joins(:photos)` (which performs an inner join) will return the properties that have related photos. Meaning photos that have a `property_id`. While the answer using `left_outer_joins`, `LEFT JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will work, it's using the left join incorrectly by having the `.where(photos: { id: nil })`. `INNER JOIN`, `JOIN`, or `joins` between Property and Photo will result in what I have stated at the beginning of this answer. The left joins will return **all** properties with or without related photos.

[image]

Comment: Not really sure the downvote. It's literally the same answer that got 2 upvotes